# Substring from first half of a delimated string field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring, delimiter

I have a Field value in SQL Server's table which contains the path of file, that path is delimited with  `-` character ,What I want is to select the sub-string from beginning (zero index) to last occurrence of that delimited character.

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(500)        
SELECT @path = 'F:\Fruit Seeds-Category Oil\Quality- Fine Seeds',
```

I need to extract sub-string **"F:\Fruit Seeds-Category Oil\Quality"** only

**My Query**

```
SELECT LEFT(@path, LEN(@path) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@path)))
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You are getting the result from your question

Comment: Yes, but I want other solution then this

Comment: You mean - **THE BEST WAY TO IMPLEMENT THIS** ? @DareDevil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds the last index of "-" in the string:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(500) = 'F:\Fruit Seeds-Category Oil\Quality- Fine Seeds';

DECLARE @i  INT = 1;
DECLARE @ix INT = 0;

WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN
    SET @ix = @i;
    SET @i = CHARINDEX('-', @Path, @i + 1);
END

SELECT LEFT(@path, @ix - 1)
```

You can clearly put it inside a function for reuse.